# awkで大きい数の平均を出そうとすると桁溢れしてしまう

Tags: shellscript, awk

vmstat -a 5 で取得した、数日分のファイルがあります。
メモリ使用率の平均を算出するために、Freeの使用量平均を知りたいのですが、awkで加算すると桁溢れしてしまい、上手くいきません。

シェルスクリプトの中で以下のように
しています。

```
VAR=`awk '{m+=$4} END{print m/NR;}' ${myfile}`
```

良い方法がありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: お使いの awk が GNU awk で、GNU MP ライブラリをリンクしているバージョンであれば `-M` オプションか `--bignum` オプションで多倍長演算が可能です。bc, python, perl, ruby なども多倍長演算に対応しているのでそれらを使うのも良いかもしれません。

Comment: `awk '{print $4}'  | paste -sd+ | bc`でいかがでしょう

Comment: 「桁溢れ」とはどういった現象でしょうか。指数表記を避けるという事でしたら、awk '{m+=$4} END{printf "%d\n", m/NR;}' などで出来ます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それぞれの方法を試したところ、上手く行きました。

Comment: 出来ましたら桁溢れで上手くいかない、というのがどういう状況だったのか教えていただけますか？emasakaさんの回答でなぜ上手くいくのか等、とても興味がありますので。(浮動小数点数の問題だとは思うのですが)

Comment: すみません。指数表記のことを桁溢れと表現してしまいました。
最終的に使用させていただいたのは以下です

awk  '{m+=($5-m)/NR;} END{printf "%d\n", m;}' vmstat.log

その後、平均使用率を算出するために

awk --bignum '{printf "%4.2f", 25609812/232100000}'

としたところ、欲しかった値（＊100でパーセントになる値）が取得できました。
（Freeは＄4でなく$5でした）

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ a+=($4-a)/NR } END{ print a }'
```

Comment: とてもスマートなやり方で、思い通りの結果になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: とてもスマートな方法で、おそらく平均を求めるベストプラクティスだと思います。しかし、必ずしも浮動小数点数の精度の問題を回避できる分けでは無いので、その点は注意して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

#### 表記の問題

表示が指数表記(科学表記)になるのを避けるには、`printf`を使いフォーマットを指定する方法があります。

```
printf "%d\n", m;
```

`OFMT`であらかじめ`print`("f"が付かない方)が使うフォーマットを決めておく方法もあります。

```
BEGIN{OFMT="%d"}
```

#### データが巨大な場合

今回の質問者さんのケースは違っていましたが、
巨大なデータの平均などを出す場合、一つの浮動小数点数に集積していく計算方法だとどうしても精度の問題があります。計算方法を工夫しても、後半のデータが反映されない等の気付きづらい問題が発生しがちです。

この場合は他の方のコメントのように、任意精度演算（多倍長演算）が行なえる物を使うのが簡単です。
一定期間毎に平均を出しておいて、後でそれらの平均を求める方法もありますね。